# namespace specialization in template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

I have two different namespaces that implement identical methods and classes in two different ways. I am writing a class that used this methods and classes to do something, I was wondering if there was a way to declare the namespace without partial  specialization as below:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace one
{
int test()
{
    return 1;
}
}

namespace two
{
int test()
{
    return 2;
}
}

enum names : int
{
    first = 1,
    second = 2
};

template <names>
struct base_class;

template <>
struct base_class<names::first>
{
    using namespace ::one;
};

template <>
struct base_class<names::second>
{
    using namespace ::two;
};

template <names ns>
struct delcare_namespace : public base_class<ns>
{
    delcare_namespace()
    {
        std::cout << test() << "\n";
    }
};
```

for the code above, I get

> test’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: `using namespace` is not allowed in class scope.

Comment: @Jaa-c. I know, this code is just a demo of what I need, is there a work-around for this ?

Comment: This seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the *real* problem you want to solve with a solution like that?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: It actually is a real problem I want to solve, I have a class that provides an interface for system socket, there are three more implementation of that socket that provide similar methods in different namespaces, If I could do something like this, I would be able o simplify all the classes into one and maintain one code

Comment: @apramc: The best I can think of is adding a member to the inherited class like this `static constexpr auto test = &one::test;` and than in `delcare_namespace` call `this->test()`. But there is no way to somehow use namespace or declare namespace alias in the class scope.

Comment: Good to know. Now can you please edit your question to include that motivation behind the code you show? Knowing *why* you want to do something like that help us help you. Knowing the motivation, someone might even be able to give you a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`using namespace` is not allowed in class scope, nor is namespace alias. I don't think you can do a specialization that would somehow inject the namespace.

It's not exactly the same, but if it's an option to declare all the functions you need from that namespace in the specialization, you can make the function pointer as a member of that specialization:

```
template <names>
struct base_class;

template <>
struct base_class<names::first>
{
    static constexpr auto test = &one::test;
};

template <>
struct base_class<names::second>
{
    static constexpr auto test = &two::test;
};

template <names ns>
struct delcare_namespace : public base_class<ns>
{
    delcare_namespace()
    {
        std::cout << this->test() << "\n";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if there was a way to declare the namespace

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible inside a class/struct and inheriting it.

> is there a work-around for this ?

The best I can imagine (if you can heavily modify your code) is transform your two namespaces in two different classes or structs, so the functions become methods (maybe `static` methods)

```
struct baseOne  // former namespace one
 {
   static int test ()
    { return 1; }
 };

struct baseTwo // former namespace two
 {
   static int test ()
    { return 2; }
 };
```

so you can pass the base class (former namespace) as template parameter and inherit from it

```
template <typename B>
struct foo : public B
 {
   foo ()
    { std::cout << B::test() << "\n"; }
 };
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct baseOne  // former namespace one
 {
   static int test ()
    { return 1; }
 };

struct baseTwo // former namespace two
 {
   static int test ()
    { return 2; }
 };

template <typename B>
struct foo : public B
 {
   foo ()
    { std::cout << B::test() << "\n"; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   foo<baseOne> f1; // print 1
   foo<baseTwo> f2; // print 2
 }
```

If the use of the `B::` before the method names is annoying for you, you can transform the `static` methods inside the bases structs in ordinary methods or add directives as

```
using B::test;
```

inside `foo`.